# Android Studio Data Binding by default

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

How do i enable data binding **by default** whenever i create a new project in Android Studio?

NOTE: I know how to enable data binding **manually**, i just want it to be there **automatically** whenever a new *compatible* project is made.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe that there has been any officially supported way to change the new-project templates.

Answer (score 0):

Found a somewhat official way,

Make a `gradle.properties` file in `<USER_HOME/.gradle>` , it will override the project level `gradle.properties` and enable `dataBinding` or whatever `buildFeatures` you need there.

Resources →

- [New options to enable or disable build features](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#buildFeatures)
- [Gradle properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)

Also community here is so unwelcoming , anyway here's the answer for future devs.

Comment: Yes i'm the author of this question, edit: gradle is automation tool, its there for automation.